# How may I check an empty feeder in gatling before moving ahead with actual execution

Tags: gatling

I want to run my simulation against two set of data. One set gives empty feeder issue and other one don't. I want to write a generic code in gatling which can handle both data sets. I would like to avoid simple if-else conditions for the variable I am setting in feeder. Also changing the data is not an option available to me.

In short, I want my execution to be skipped if my feeder is empty. Is it possible through gatling way ?

```
exec(
    randomSwitch(33.0 -> feed(data1.random).exec(step1),
      33.0 -> feed(data2.random).exec(step2),
      34.0 -> feed(data3.random).exec(step3)
    ))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
 scenario("Requests").feed(orderRefs).group("Groups") {
  asLongAs(session => jobsQue.length > 0) {
     exec { session => you code
          }
```